# Get currently authenticated user against Active Directory through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, authentication, active-directory

I'm (we're here at my company) facing a challenge. We're being asked by most of our clients (if not all of them) to automatically authenticate a user with their previously-entered windows authentication, which is going against a LDAP Active Directory. The app is a web app running in .NET webforms, but we're currently in design phase for the second version which will make the jump towards MVC, if that's of any help.

## Behaviour

- User opens a Windows session authenticating against Active Directory
- User opens the browser and goes to his/hers company's installation of our product (most of the time installed in a local server, but it might installed outside)
- The page has to check whether the user is authenticated via Active Directory and, if he/she is, authenticate the user into the app (for the sake of simplicity, the same login name in AD has to be registered in our app in advanced)
- If not (the user didn't login against AD), then prompt for user credentials, and authenticate those credentials against AD.

The problem I'm facing is that I don't know **how to retrieve this 2 things**:

- ***Which* authentication method** the user used to get in. I actually only need to know if it was through AD or not.
- **The username** he/she used (that would be the username of the current windows session).

I'm pretty confident that this would have to be done through javascript, but in case it **can't**, we're ok with developing a little plugin for the browsers to get to the necessary Windows API function.

Please let me know your thoughts on the matter, and whether you need any more information.

Comment: are the sites exclusively intranet sites? If they aren't not sure you want to autologin via domain creds for security reasons, regardless if it is possible or not.

Comment: They might or they might not, depending on what the client wants to do with the software. I'm pretty sure the AD server is going to be "indoors only", that's why we provide a secondary login in case someone connects from outside the corporate's firewall. Anyway, why would it be risky? I'm not proficient on Active Directory, but does it not send things over a secure channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding that NTLM and Kerberos would be part of your solution, and this appears to be covered in detail in this question:

[How does SSO using Active Directory works where user is transparently logged in. (intranet webapp)](https://serverfault.com/questions/293171/how-does-sso-using-active-directory-works-where-user-is-transparently-logged-in)

Alternatively, have you heard of [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com)? (Disclaimer: I work there).  Stormpath offers a read-only REST API on top of your Active Directory instance, allowing you to quickly write web applications that can authenticate against your AD environment.

You can learn more here: [Integrating Stormpath with Active Directory and LDAP](https://docs.stormpath.com/guides/ad-ldap/)

Comment: Thanks for the info. We're currently looking at Kerberos as our most probable course of action, but I will need a lot more info on the matter (maybe after the 3rd bokk I'll stop... to make a coffee :D) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Answer accepted!